# BroadcastReceiver does not react on notifications created in GmcService

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, broadcastreceiver, notificationcenter

Using Xamarin.Android.

I have a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            string someExtra = intent.Extras.GetString("someExtra", string.Empty);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I use a Google Cloud Messaging Service and create a notification when receive some message. Using a notification builder's SetContentIntent I export some extras to the activity that will operate this notification if user opens it. And it works. But when I initialize my notification builder with SetDeleteIntent inside the GCM Service, the notification does not trigger OnReceive in the BroadcastReceiver if user swipe to dismiss the notification.

When I do all the same inside my activity (not inside the GCM service) OnReceive is triggered on every notification's swipe-to-dismiss event. But it does not work inside the service.

I have even implemented the same CreateNotification method in my activity as in the service. When I call it (to create the notification) from my activity - all works perfect. When I call it from the service using a static pointer to the current instance of the activity - MyActivity.CurrentInstance.CreateNotification(...) - my notification does not react on swipe-to-dismiss event. I even tried to put the CreateNotification's code in RunOnUiThread - no result.

Therefore, notification's swipe-to-dismiss event is triggered only in case if that notification has been created in my activity. But I create notifications when receive messages from GCM. It actually creates notifications even when application is not running.

```
public void CreateNotification(........) {
    //RunOnUiThread(() => {
    var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.SetContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.SetContentText(description);
    notificationBuilder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

    var notificationIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
         notificationIntent.PutExtra(.......)
    var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
    notificationBuilder.SetContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Actually my headache
    const String NOTIFICATION_DELETED_ACTION = "NOTIFICATION_DELETED";
    var receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    RegisterReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(NOTIFICATION_DELETED_ACTION));
    Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION_DELETED_ACTION);
         intent.PutExtra(.......)
    var deleteIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
    notificationBuilder.SetDeleteIntent(deleteIntent);

    var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
    notificationManager.Notify(1, notificationBuilder.Build());
    //});
}
```

Any ideas how to create a notification (inside the service) that will be able to trigger its swipe-to-dismiss event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> notification's swipe-to-dismiss event is triggered only in case if that notification has been created in my activity

When you When you use `SetDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)` method, make sure your `deleteIntent` is initialized by using `PendingIntent.GetBroadcast` method.

`GetBroadcastet` means retrieve a `PendingIntent` that will perform a broadcast, like calling `Context.sendBroadcast()`. When you use `GetActivity` method, it means retrieve a `PendingIntent` that will start a new activity. That's reason that your notification does not trigger `OnReceive` in the `BroadcastReceiver`.  For more information you could read this [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

Modify your code :

```
 var deleteIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
```

To :

```
 var deleteIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
```

Then in your GCM Service, your notification's swipe-to-dismiss event will be triggered .

Comment: Thank you. GetBroadcast is a great spell. My headache has gone, thanks to your magic)))
But it works only if I call CreateNotification using a static pointer to the current instance of the activity - MyActivity.CurrentInstance.CreateNotification(...). CreateNotification declared in the service does not do the magic.

Comment: @Vitaliy Hanych, happy coding. : )

Comment: But is there any way to force BroadcastReceiver to react on the event of the notification that I create in my service? When the application is not running, I can't call MyActivity.CurrentInstance.CreateNotification().

Therefore I can operate notification's swipe-to-dismiss event only if the application is running.

Comment: @Vitaliy Hanych, it's a little complex, you could post a new question for a better answer.  : )

Comment: OK. Thank you for advice.